# How to disable long touch in UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview, uiwindow, uiwebviewdelegate

I want to disable long-touch from the application. I have no control on the HTML that I am loading on my WebView.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate I run a javascript on the loaded html page that disable the long touch.

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none'; document.body.style.KhtmlUserSelect='none'"];
```

Comment: I have added the same line.. But it's not working. Don't know what is going wrong.. :(
In most of the links I found the same solution as above..

Comment: - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView {
    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none'; document.body.style.KhtmlUserSelect='none'"];
}

But still not working for me

Comment: @Denny this answer is from 2015 I might that webkit have changed a bit since then. The idea should be the same, inject javascript in to the web view that will disable the long touch.

Comment: You can also add : `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none';"];` for Objective-C or `webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none';")` for Swift

Answer (score 9):

The UIWebView is no longer supported. So, you should implement WKWebView and there is a property called **allowsLinkPreview** with that you can enable or disable the long touch previews.

```
 webView.allowsLinkPreview = false
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to override the following methods from the view controller :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

this way you can replace the usual touches management with your own implementation.

Answer (score -6):

Open your view in Interface Builder, click on the web view and then un-check the "User Interaction Enabled" checkbox in the attributes inspector.

If you want to do it in code, set the web view's [`userInteractionEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-userinteractionenabled) property to `NO`.

Comment: That disables all interaction does it not? Not just long touch?