# iPhone: How to Disable UIWebView Selection

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable Copy and Paste in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676369/how-to-disable-copy-and-paste-in-uiwebview)

Any suggestions how to remove page items highlight on WebView..Like when you tap on text, text area become grey and menu with "copy, select, paste" appears...Can I disable that thing ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible dupliate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676369/how-to-disable-copy-and-paste-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to set setUserInteractionEnabled:false?
It should work for most cases.

Comment: This will also prevent interaction with links, video etc.

Comment: Well I supposed it was a case when you want to use a UIWebView as an enhanced UILabel to render text but yo do not want the user to interact with it...