# How to disable long press gesture on UIWebView of iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm just wondering how to disable the long press gesture on webview in iOS.
I need to disable only long press gesture not others.
should work on iOS 5.0 +
thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314193/how-to-disable-long-touch-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make UIWebView as a super class to one of your custom class, extend it.. and override touchesBegan.. methods from UIView class..

Answer (score 3):

I want to thank all for help. I finally found the solution after intensive stackoverflow research. For help other :

In the javascript/html, you can avoid dealing with the longpress event.

The solution was given  long time ago : [Preventing default context menu on longpress / longclick in mobile Safari (iPad / iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304012/preventing-default-context-menu-on-longpress-longclick-in-mobile-safari-ipad)

I did it and it is just perfect. Thanks and thanks again.

JM