# How do I correctly disable link detection in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview

I Have a UIWebView strictly for viewing PDF's, and I don't want any link detection in the view, Like this:

[image]

So I added the following code to negate the detection of links and the presentation of that view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.None

    }
```

However it still picks up links, and presents that modal view. How do I correctly implement code to stop this?

Here is my updated code:

```
class PdfViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var myWebView: UIWebView!


    var contentUrlPassedOn: String!

    var allowLoad = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myWebView.delegate = self

        let url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: contentUrlPassedOn)
        myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))

        myWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.None
   }


    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        return allowLoad
    }


    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        var hasFinishedLoading = false

        updateProgress()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))),
            dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                [weak self] in
                if let _self = self {
                    _self.hasFinishedLoading = true

                    self!.allowLoad = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: that did not work @KiritModi

Comment: you are adding below code in WebView Delegate

Comment: check my updated question, added my current code @KiritModi

Comment: give me What is URL of your pdf

Comment: why, i have hundreds of them @KiritModi not just one

Comment: how do i just turn off the detection @KiritModi

Comment: I want one for Testing

Comment: can't you just use any link  to a online pdf @KiritModi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89576/discussion-between-kirit-modi-and-john-durand).

Answer (score 3):

If your webview was added by the storyboard, You can disable this in the attributes inspector.

[[image: Xcode Image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xij8b.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's an objective-c code, but u can do the same in Swift. It will fix the interaction with links. The con is that they will be still detected.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
if (inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

}

Comment: Will it still present that modal prompt ?

Comment: Well, I think it should not, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: it fixes interaction with the links

Comment: however when i hold the links down, the prompt still shows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314193/how-to-disable-long-touch-in-uiwebview

Comment: Found also one for pdf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768194/uiwebview-without-copy-paste-when-displaying-pdf-files

Answer (score 0):

Finely Solve the problem for you,

[Working Demo](http://ge.tt/1AErntN2/v/0)

Cannot disable long press link menu, Which is Bug in iOS, That's solve in iOS 8.2.

According to bug, when press long on link then its open Action Sheet, Now in iOS 8.2 its solve as below.

Load PDF using `WKWebView` as below.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        super.viewDidLoad()
        var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.nursing.umich.edu/studentresources/documentation/CreatingBookmarksPDFdocsV7.pdf")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)


    }

}
```

Now you Click on your long Press link then its doesn't open ActionSheet PopUp.

Enjoy..!!

Output :

[image]

Comment: if I create my webView through `UIWebKit` how would I use all my `UIWebViewDelegate` methods?

Comment: because those `UIWebViewDelegate` methods help track progress loading, amongst other things